# Hide Image until a value is given

Tags: java, android, sprite

I am making an app and I have it working somewhat, but thankfully I know what my problem is. I have a sprite that moves around border and I want the sprite to shoot a ball at a particular spot. Currently, my app displays the ball at position (0,0) and then shoots it over when it is supposed to. It does this by adding 10 to x in an update method thus its an animation, I can speed it up for slow it down by changing 10. The variable x and y have a default of 0. I than change them as specified above. I want them to remain 0 as default but I do not want the ball to display until it is moving. Right now it displays the ball on startup, and then moves. I want it to display ball once I give x and y values.

Here is a snippet of current code.

```
        // This moves the ball down the right side of screen
        if (x > ov.getWidth() - width - xSpeed){
            xSpeed = 0;
            ySpeed = 10;
            direction = 1;
            shootL(); // shoots the ball left towards the left side of screen

        }

              // moves ball up the screen on left side
        if (x + xSpeed < 0){
            x = 0;
            xSpeed = 0;
            ySpeed = -10;
            direction = 3;
            shootR();  // shoots the ball towards right side of screen
        }


    private void shootR() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // need to manipulate variable q to go across screen
        q += 10;
           // eventually manipulate r so that it shoots at the right spot on screen, not my major problem right now.

    }


    private void shootL() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // need to manipulate variable q to go across screen
        q += -10;
           // eventually manipulate r so that it shoots at the right spot on screen, not my major problem right now.
    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        update();
        int srcY = direction * height;
        Rect src = new Rect (0, srcY, width, srcY + height);
        Rect dst = new Rect (x, y, x+width, y+height);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, src,  dst, null); // draws sprite around border
        Paint p = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(fire, q, r, p); // draws ball that shoots across


    }
```

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Its just displaying the ball at the wrong time and I need to fix this. Must be an error or something.

Comment: Assuming that the ball is part of your layout xml file, you can keep that view INVISIBLE or GONE unless and until you have provided the x & y co-ordinates. Is that not the case here?

Comment: @Rajeev, I am doing a surface View rather than an xml layout.

Comment: yeah...I had seen your answer. i had given my comment before you posted the answer. You should accept your answer.

Comment: @Rajeev can't do that until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I was clueless. I figured it Out. I had the changing of the coordinates in an update method which was called in an onDraw method. The onDraw method went through every line of code and then was called again updating one at a time. By adding an if statement in onDraw and removing the changing of q in update and moving it into the if statement it didnt draw until the if was true.

**I was drawing before I was changing. You need to change variables, and then draw!**